# Filter out a result that only contains double quotes using PHP

Tags: php, string

I am retrieving some product options from my database, if a product has those options then a json object is saved to my db but if it does not have any options the column just contains `""`.

I tried to filter it out with :

```
if(!empty($artikel['aantalkuub']){

}
```

But its not empty or NULL because the double quotes are in it, so I tried this:

```
if(!empty($artikel['aantalkuub']) OR $artikel['aantalkuub'] != '""'){

}
```

But that also is not working.

How can I check on those double quotes? And only if that is all there is, because a product that does have the options has the json object between those quotes.

Comment: that seems odd considering empty checks for that ... https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: You could escape the double quotes like this ( [...] != "\"\""). Haven't tried it yet, hop it works.

Comment: @treyBake Weird.. but after trimming it like in the answer below, the check works so I am not sure why `""` is not seen as empty.

Comment: @twan then it wasn't just `""` - it contained a whitespace character :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the `"` from the string and check if it is empty:

```
if (!empty(trim($artikel['aantalkuub'], '" '))) {

}
```

Comment: this seems like the only viable thing :S

Answer (score 0):

you can replace double quotes like below then check if it's empty

```
if(!empty(str_replace('"', "", $artikel['aantalkuub']))){
  ....
}
```